# How to find inverse of function?

Tags: calculus, functions

$f\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}  } , \frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}  } \right)  $

How do I find inverse function? I have trouble here, because there are 2 variables and I am not sure how to do it?

Comment: Hint: what is $f(f(x, y))$?

Comment: Your function $f$ is from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, so it can be represented in a matrix we say for example $A$. Now you find $A^{-1}$ if it is exists

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe there **is** an inverse to this function?  You are mapping every point in $R^2$ (except (0, 0)) to $R$.

Comment: Only **linear** functions can be represented by matrices.  This function is not linear.

Comment: Are you from Croatia? Or maybe Serbia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is the same as always when you have to find an inverse:

Set $u = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \quad v  = \frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ and solve for $x,y$.

You can easily see immediately that $u^2+v^2 = \frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$ and therefore $x^2+y^2 = \frac{1}{u^2+v^2}$.

From the equations above we then get $$x = u\cdot (x^2+y^2) = \frac{u}{u^2+v^2}$$

and similarly

$$y = v\cdot (x^2+y^2) = \frac{v}{u^2+v^2}$$

So $f$ is it's own inverse on $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{0\}$.

In fact, this particular map is well known as [*circle inversion*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Inversion.html). It is basically mirroring the points on a mirror shaped like an unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

your function maps every point $\mathbf{p}\in\mathbb R \setminus \{0\}$ to $\mathbf{p} / (\|\mathbf{p} \|^2)$, the same point but divided by its norm squared. So the direction is unchanged but the size is inverted. To 'undo' this you simply apply the same function again.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x,y)=(a,b)\implies f^{-1}(a,b)=(x,y)$ Therefore$$a={x\over x^2+y^2}\ ;\ b={y\over x^2+y^2}$$

$$a^2+b^2 = \frac{x^2+y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}$$ So $$x^2+y^2 = \frac{1}{a^2+b^2}$$.

Now check$$x = a (x^2+y^2) = \frac{a}{a^2+b^2}$$

Do exactly the same operations with $y$ and you are left with
 $$x={a\over a^2+b^2}\ ;\ y={b\over a^2+b^2}$$

As said before (and it fortunately turns out that) $f^{-1}(a,b)=\left({a\over a^2+b^2},{b\over a^2+b^2}\right)=f(a,b)$

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic I have solved it entirely for you. Happy? :-) Please accept if you liked my answer.

Comment: This answer is similar to the one given previously by @flawr

Comment: @user84413 In a previous comment (which the OP has deleted) she asked me to do the solving explicitly. So I did it.

Answer (score 0):

$$ \left(x_{inv},y_{inv}\right) \rightarrow \left(\frac{a^2 x}{x^{2}+y^{2}  }, \frac{a^2y}{x^{2}+y^{2}  } \right)  $$

The inverse of right bracket is the original left bracket itself.

The two way mapping can be geometrically best illustrated /explained as an inversion geometrically.
The red circle with radius $ a $ reflects outside this circle to inside and vice-versa.
$$ r\rightarrow 1/r $$ if inverted with respect to unit circle and,
$$ r\rightarrow a^2/r $$ if inverted with respect  to a circle radius $a$.

[Inversion](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=inversion%20circle&rlz=1C9BKJA_enIN690IN690&hl=en-GB&prmd=inv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-9IjtkLLNAhXIuo8KHe2MD5QQ_AUIBygB&biw=1024&bih=653#imgrc=XZyazrKoPyJL2M%3A)