# How to show is function surjective?

Tags: calculus, functions

$f\left(x,y\right)=\left(\frac{x}{x^{2}+y^{2}  } , \frac{y}{x^{2}+y^{2}  } \right)  $

$R^{2}-(0,0)$

Can someone help me with shwoing that this function is surjective?

Comment: How is the function defined at $(0,0)$?

Comment: Hint: how do you get a large value of $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$?

Comment: It is not defined. It is $R{^2 }-(0,0)$

Comment: @almagest when $x^{2}+y^{2}$ is smaller as it can be?

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic So it would help if you stated in the question that $f$ was a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Yes, you need $y$ small as well as $x$ small to get a large value of $\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$. Can you see how to develop that train of thought.

Comment: But I still dont understand how to show that is surjective?

Comment: Asked and answered-here you go.  [Is function invertible?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830158/is-function-invertible)

Comment: Could you please refrain from asking [minor variants](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831072) of the [same question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1830158)? Thank you.

Comment: But I dont understand previous answers!

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic: If you don't understand an answer someone has left, you're welcome (even encouraged!) to ask for clarification in the comments beneath the respective answer. By contrast, asking the same question anew causes the community to duplicate effort, and tends to create confusion as people reply to comments addressed elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

As in the [answer to your previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1831072/how-to-find-inverse-of-function/1831093#1831093) check that $f(x,y)=f^{-1}(x,y)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\}$. Since $f(x,y)$ is defined on every value of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\}\ \therefore$ $f^{-1}(x,y)$ is also  defined on every value of $\mathbb{R}^2\backslash \{0\}$. Since this means that to every image there is a preimage $\therefore$ $f$ is surjective

Comment: But I should show that function is surjective, before I found inverse?

Comment: Suggestion :put $x=r cos \theta \\y= r sin \theta$ so you will have $f =(\frac{cos \theta}{r},\frac{sin \theta}{r})$ and , this function is surjective

Comment: @AnaMatijanovic You can always find out the inverse first and check on which points it is defined and whether every image has a preimage..

Answer (score 0):

Before you can ask if the function is *surjective*, you have to specify what is the *codomain* of the function (now I read that the domain is $R^2\setminus (\mathbf 0)$).
However, interpreting the lack of such specification as an underlying assumption of the largest possible codomain, that is
$$
f:\mathbb R^2\setminus (\mathbf 0)\to \mathbb R^2,
$$
then $f$ would not be surjective because $\mathbf 0$ is never attained. However
$$
f:\mathbb R^2\setminus (\mathbf 0)\to \mathbb R^2\setminus (\mathbf 0),
$$
 is surjective. In fact, in vector notation, $f(\mathbf r)=\mathbf r/|\mathbf r|^2$, therefore, for $\mathbf y\neq\mathbf 0$
$$
\frac{\mathbf r}{|\mathbf r|^2}=\mathbf y\qquad \iff\quad \frac{\mathbf y}{|\mathbf y|^2}=\mathbf r.
$$
Therefore $f$ is actually bijective on that domain and
$$
f=f^{-1}.
$$